# Thank you TeX.SE!

Tags: discussion, community

I just got my first book published and I would like to thank everyone here at TeX.SE for the help that they provided by answering the questions that I posted. I know that accepting an answer is considered a "Thank you" but I wanted to say it personally.

Thank you!

---

I don't want to advertise here but if you're interested you can find the book [here](http://www.amazon.ca/The-Clockworks-of-Wall-Street/dp/1482575450/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1369662897&sr=8-1&keywords=The%20Clockworks%20of%20Wall%20Street).

Comment: Related: https://www.facebook.com/FLOInitiative/posts/468296723254383 `;)`

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Holy crap! How did you find that? hahah

Comment: I googled for [`"The Clockworks of Wall Street"`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22The+Clockworks+of+Wall+Street%22).

Comment: Well, our reviewers are getting lazy, the *thank you* is not removed. I'm impressed.

Comment: @percusse :D :D

Comment: @percusse: I was just thinking the same! just imagine what wuld be left of the message, if all the 'Thank you's were removed... `:D`